# Lazy loading pages with BrowserRouter Lazy and Suspense

Tags: reactjs

Lazily loading routes makes sense as these are often the root of many a component tree. I'd like to be able to show the current route while the next route is loading. Users expect a little wait on page loads.

The error im getting is `Error: A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified. Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.`

The code im using is...

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./home'));
const Props = lazy(() => import('./props'));
const State = lazy(() => import('./state'));


const Router: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path = '/' component = {Home} />
        <Route exact path = '/state' component = {State} />
        <Route exact path = '/props' component = {Props} />
        <Suspense fallback={Home}>
          <Route component = {Home}/>
        </Suspense>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap `Suspense` around `Switch`.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = lazy(() => import("./home"));
const About = lazy(() => import("./about"));

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading..</div>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Instead of showing the Loading... message is there a way to just show the current page? Or better still pass a loading prop to the current page?

Comment: Suspense means till the time your route is not loaded, you want to show some indicator to user, you are essentially asking to show the component while waiting for that very component.

Comment: Avoid Home component to be loaded lazily. Inside the Home component you could load other components lazily.